# How to use `btn` with `pagination` in bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create pagination with Bootstrap and Angular. For now, it looks like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let page of pages" [class.active]="page.isActive">
    <span class="page-link btn" (click)="pageChange(page.number)">{{page.text}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I can't make buttons behave like buttons/anchors. I would like to see hand cursor while hovering over. How can I do it?

Comment: The ``<span>`` in your code snippet is already acting like a button. ``.btn`` class adds ``cursor: pointer``. There is something else happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the following:

```
| `$enable-pointer-cursor-for-buttons` | `true` (default) or `false` | 
                               Add "hand" cursor to non-disabled button elements.|
```

And in `_buttons.scss` we have:

```
.btn {
  ...
  cursor: if($enable-pointer-cursor-for-buttons, pointer, null);
  ...
}
```

So changing `span` to `button` makes it work

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let page of pages" [class.active]="page.isActive">
    <button class="page-link btn" (click)="pageChange(page.number)">{{page.text}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```